# Distinct() not working

Tags: c#, .net, collections, lambda, distinct

I am trying to fetch a list of distinct values from a collection. But I am unable to do so.

For example:

```
var someValue = (Data.Cast<IDetailType>().Select(x => x.Common.Provider)
                                         .Union(Data.Cast<NDetailType>().Select(x => x.Common.Provider))).Distinct();
```

This query returns me all sets of Data, along with repetition data also.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Distinct , how to compare the objects , please see the overload `Distinct(IEqualityComparer<T>)`

and see the [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/04/05/linq-distinct-and-iequalitycomparer-implementation.aspx) how to do it